Do form builder forms work embeded on wordpress pages?
I manage two different sites and each of them crash when i embed a form builder form on the page. I use the shortcode E.G. [civicrm component="afform" name="afformFORMNAME"]
Without fail, it crashes the page. Is it not ready for embed on front end pages?
Thanks!

There is a bug report filed for this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5553
With the following proposed fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/337
The PR is still open, which means it is in need of testing. Please try out the fix for yourself and leave a comment on the PR giving feedback about whether it fixes your problem. This review will help the PR to get merged.
